# Is it safe to delete puppet user after uninstalling puppet and puppet-common?

Tags: debian, puppet, etcpasswd

In Debian I installed puppet with `apt-get install puppet`.

Later I decided to uninstall it with `apt-get purge puppet puppet-common`.

However I just noticed my /etc/passwd file still contains the line for puppet:

`puppet:x:107:115:Puppet configuration management daemon,,,:/var/lib/puppet:/bin/false`

Is this user still around for any reason? Any harm from `userdel -r puppet` since puppet itself is no longer installed in my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine to delete this user.